# temperature of a component on pcb

Tags: pcb, temperature

i have designed a pcb which includes RF power amplifier , so while using for thee testing purpose i want to know the power consumed by the each component on pcb , i found a way to find out the power from the relation of power and temperature so How can I measure the temperature of a component(R/L/C) on PCB ?

Comment: How much accuracy/precision do you need?

Comment: Please update your initial question instead of posting a new one. The requirement and context are still very similar. Also, capitalization and spelling are important and help a lot in legibility.

Answer (score 2):

Most folks use a DMM with a thermocouple attachment. Here's a pic of an adapter that can be used with any DMM, but even low cost ones often come with a thermocouple:

[image: Thermocouple adapter for DMM]

The advantage to a thermocouple:

1. Very low thermal mass. Heats and cools very quickly.
2. Handles very high and very low temperatures.
3. Very small measuring area; can be attached to small components

Also, most engineers use Kapton tape to stick it on components. Just Google "Kapton tape". It can handle high temperatures without melting (e.g. 260 deg-C, 500 deg-F).

[image: Kapton Tape]

But I'd like to make a point: before the product gets to this stage, a good engineer would have already been designing for power, calculating the power dissipation of critical components especially in the final RF stage.

A good engineer would have:

1. Reviewed the datasheet of the capacitor and looked at the dissipation factor of the capacitor at the frequency of interest and computed the power dissipation at the capacitor.
2. Reviewed the datasheet of the inductor for the effective series resistance and the loss at the frequency of interested. Calculated the power loss at the inductor.
3. Reviewed the datasheet of the transistor, computed the power dissipation of the transistor.
4. Reviewed the heatsinking and computed the temperature rise of the power transistor.

And then he would run a simulation of the circuit to not only confirm its operation but check if his power calculations were correct.

After the circuit is built, he would then use the thermal measurements to check against his initial calculations and his simulation results.

A hobbyist would simply build the circuit, check if it works, and see which component releases the magic smoke and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a thermometer. You can use an IR thermometer, or attach a sensor to the part. You can get very small thermistors that would be good for this. If you use an IR thermometer, the surface can affect the reading.

Comment: Thanks for the information , and i have a doubt that the components on pcb  are very small in size right , by using thermometer can we get the accurate values of temperature of each component individually ?

Comment: It depends on your requirements and how make your measurement.

Answer (score 0):

A sheet of copper foil --- standard thickness is 1 ounce of CU per square foot --- has 70 degree Centigrade thermal resistance per square of foil. Assuming there is no radiation nor convection, and assuming the heat cannot flow laterally out of the foil, e.g. down into underlying planes or traces.

That square can be 0.1 inch square or 4" (0.1 meter) square, however the math remains the same.

The thermal resistance of this group of traces

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0wZWg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

given there are 5 squares, is 5 * 70 = 350 degree Centigrade per watt.

A trace length 1" and width 0.05", thus 20 squares, has 1,400 degree C per watt of thermal resistance. Ignoring all the other possible paths.